# should __exit__ superclass method be called from subclass in python

Tags: python, subclass, exit, superclass

I am not sure why this even dawned on me but if I have a context manager compliant class that is a subclass of another context manager class as shown below.  I have shown the "typical" model where __exit__ calls close().  My question is: should bar.__exit__() explicitly call super(bar,self).__exit__(args) or should bar's close() call foo's close or??? What is the recommend model here in this case?

```
class foo(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        pass
    def __exit__(self,*exc_info):
        self.close()
        return False
    def close(self):
      pass
class bar(foo):
    def __enter__(self):
        pass
    def __exit__(self,*exc_info):
        self.close()
        return False
    def close(self):
        super(bar,self).close()   # is this the recommend model?
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the superclass's behavior to take effect, or not?  It depends whether you want to replace or extend the superclass behavior.

Answer (score 2):

As it might be impossible to know in general case what the `__exit__` method does, I'd call it with the same arguments; if I want to throw an exception, then give it that exception instead in its `__exit__`, and then raise it after the exception has returned... but all in all this sounds a bit hacky; the better way could be so that you either do not override the `__exit__` and just override the `close` method (relying on the fact that it gets called anyway by the superclass); or chain these 2 context managers if they really do something different.

Comment: yes, overidding close() is the best way to do it but suppose you wanted something in you __exit__ method too.  I am asking if anyone really sees anything good or bad in terms of having an __exit__() in subclass and then calling the super().__exit__()...  I have looked at a lot of code that has __exit_ and never found a class that was a subclas so I can;t find any examples of what other authors did.

Comment: I'd say that there is hardly anything good in having an `__exit__` in subclass, as the protocol is a bit complicated